# p:outputLabel not marked as required when target input is inside composite

Tags: jsf, primefaces, label, composite-component

In a very simple way, here is a composite:

```
<ui:component 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
        <cc:attribute name="required" />
        <cc:editableValueHolder name="calendar" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" showOn="button"/>  
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Here how I use it:

```
<p:outputLabel for="rat:calendar" value="Hello" />
<my:calendar id="rat" required="true"/>
```

A required=true icon should be displayed but it does not. In OutputLabelRenderer looks fine, except in line 118, input.isRequired() returns false while I explicitly set true. I don't think it is related to Primefaces but looks like a JSF problem (I'm using Mojarra 2.2.13 and reproduced on Myfaces 2.2.4 as well)

Comment: The problem is actually in PrimeFaces.

Comment: According to them, it's not PF issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1633

Comment: Moreover I reproduced the problem with `h:outputText`

Comment: After several tests, it's a jsf impl bug. Reported here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4172 Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0):

Explanation provided by Myfaces: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4059